# IntelliJ file watcher

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, file-watcher

I setup `file watcher` to execute script on PHP files changes in my project, but it get triggered even when no files was changed.

Is it possible to see which particular change `triggered watcher`?

Comment: 1) I personally not aware of "what triggered" functionality. Please show your File Watcher settings (all options visible). It could be an external change for example. 2) At what moments such unexpected execution occurs? 3) What files it is gets triggered for?

Comment: @LazyOne, it occurs periodically every couple of seconds. That what I was asking about, how do I see the name of files it triggered for?

Comment: *"That what I was asking about, how do I see the name of files it triggered for?"* That's not clear at all from your question. For me it sounds like "what cased File Watcher to run" and by "what" I mean NOT a file name but an actual event (e.g. detected modified date change, content change etc).

Comment: In any case: just edit your File Watcher and set "Show Console" to "Always" -- it will show the full command that gets executed with params -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-file-watchers.html#ws_filewatcher_advanced_options  Alternatively (especially if it get fired for many files at once), edit File Watcher program: e.g. use your own shell/batch script where you can log the file name first ... and then execute the actual command later.